# Filter selection where [attr!=Array]

Tags: jquery, arrays, attributes

I have a `select` with countries where the value is the 2 character code.

```
<select>
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    ...
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

I want to disable all of the options that aren't in an array that's being generated.

```
var allowedCountries = ["AF", "AX", "AL", "DZ", "AS", "AD", "AO"];
```

Is there a way to do this with `.filter()` or do I have to loop through the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("option").filter(function() {
    return allowed_countries.indexOf(this.value) == -1;
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

You should probably put `""` in `allowedCountries` so they can unselect the menu. Either that, or re-enable it after filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `inArray` with `filter` :

```
$("option").filter(function (i) {
    return $.inArray(this.value, allowedCountries) == -1
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/cJVxC/1/

Comment: Other htan the fact that inArray returns the index of the item found or -1 rather than a boolean. Using it this way will be buggy.