# Find elements with existing "data-my" attribute that doesn't equal 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find all `a` elements in DOM that:

- Have attribute `data-my`
- This attribute is not "0" (it can only be "0" or higher, no negatives)

I tried:

```
$('a[data-my]').find("[data-my!='0']")
```

it gives empty array.

```
$('a[data-my!=0]')
```

This one give elements that have no `data-my` attribute besides those that have it different from 0.

Comment: `.find()` looks only for elements inside the element you start from, it doesn't include the element itself.

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It literally only takes an hour, two tops, and it pays you back that time really, really quickly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder To be fair, this is probably not something you'll find in the documentation, it takes a little extra logic to realize how to combine things properly.

Comment: @Barmar: And clearly I need to re-take my own advice (it has been several years now), in light of your comment on the now-deleted answer.

Comment: @Barmar: Re your "needle in a very large haystack" -- yeah, I was on Page 7 or so and still not finding it. :-) I *knew* it was there, but if I'd just come to the site to find it not knowing the site, I'd've given up by then.

Comment: Can the value of `data-my` ever be negative? If so, this isn't really a duplicate... The questions asks about values that are _"larger than '0'"_, so `!=` may not work, depending on the scope of the problem.

Comment: @nbrooks: Very good point, the text didn't quite match up with the bullet points there. But the edit (which I mistakenly thought was by the author) isn't really appropriate. More appropriate to wait for the OP to confirm which was correct, the bullet point or the text.

Comment: @Mike: If it really is "greater than zero," let us know, we can reopen the question or (more likely) find an alternate duplicate. For instance, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842366/filter-selection-where-attr-array), where the central point is using the `filter` function for complex situations.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , The values are 0 or more. (No negative numbers). I'll edit question to make it clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it, didn't really seem as if it was changing the meaning since it matched the body of the question, but you're right that it's better to have the OP clarify.

Comment: @nbrooks The last edit by T.J is correct - just 0 or more as a value of attribute.